# How can I clearly switch between two forms in one template (Django)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

When several html forms (signup and login) in one template, `login_signup.html`

Also I have two `views` (signup and login) which direct template, `login_signup.html`.

This is how it works.

1. When I do login (http://example.com/login), it direct to `login_signup.html` and show just `login` form. (hide `signup` form)
2. When I do signup (http://example.com/signup), it direct to `login_signup.html` and show just `signup` form. (hide `login` form)

I implement it using `javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ((window.location.pathname).indexOf('login') >= 0) {
        $('#signupbox').hide();
        $('#loginbox').show();
    } else {
        $('#loginbox').hide();
        $('#signupbox').show();
    }
});
```

Problem is though, when I want go to signup page(http://example.com/signup), it shows `login` forms in very few second and hide it and show `signup` form. I think this is not good User Interface.

How can I deal with it clearly?

Here is my whole `template` and `javascript` code.
`login_signup.html`

```
{% extends 'chacha_dabang/skeleton/base.html' %}

{% load pipeline%}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                    <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <!-- id / pw -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                            <input id="id_username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input id="id_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="btn-controls">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="login_submit" value="로 그 인" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ request.GET.next}} />
                                    <a id="btn-fblogin" href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='facebook' %}" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i> 1초만에 페이스북으로 로그인 </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                <div class="signup">
                                    아직 차차다방 회원이 아니세요? &nbsp
                                    <a href="#" id="signuplink"> 가입하기 </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="forget">
                                    <a href="#"> 비밀번호를 잊어버리셨나요? </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>  <!-- <div class="panel-body" > -->

            </div>  <!-- <div class="panel panel-info"> -->
        </div>  <!-- <div id="loginbox"> -->


        <!-- Sign up Form -->
        <div id="signupbox" class="mainbox">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Sign Up</div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'users:signup' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <!-- signup -->
                        <div id="signupalert" class="alert alert-danger">
                            <p>Error:</p>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- id / pw -->
                        <table id="signup-table">
                            <col width="30%">
                            <col width="70%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.username }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.username }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.password1.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.password1 }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.password1 }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.password2.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.password2 }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.password2 }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.name.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.name }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.name }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.gender.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.gender }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.gender }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.birth.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.birth }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.birth }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.phone_number.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.phone_number }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.phone_number }}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label-tag">{{ form.job.label_tag }}</td>
                                <td class="value">{{ form.job }}</td>
                                {{ form.errors.job}}
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="btn-controls">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input id="btn-signup" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="signup_submit" value="가 입 하 기" />
                                    <a id="btn-fblogin" href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='facebook' %}" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>1초만에 페이스북으로 로그인</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                <div class="login">
                                    이미 차차다방 회원이신가요? &nbsp
                                    <a href="#" id="loginlink"> 로그인하기 </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div> <!-- <div class="panel-body"> -->

            </div>  <!-- <div class="panel panel-info"> -->
        </div> <!-- <div id="signupbox"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="container"> -->
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}
    {% javascript "login_signup" %}
{% endblock %}
```

`login_signup.js`

```
$("#signuplink").click(function(){
    $('#loginbox').hide();
    $('#signupbox').show();
});

$("#loginlink").click(function(){
    $('#signupbox').hide();
    $('#loginbox').show();
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    if ((window.location.pathname).indexOf('login') >= 0) {
        $('#signupbox').hide();
        $('#loginbox').show();
    } else {
        $('#loginbox').hide();
        $('#signupbox').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to do this, why don't just add displat:none to the form css, then show them when you want?

Comment: @Aison What would be difference with my code ?? Could you show me some simple codes for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div id="signupbox" class="mainbox" style="display: none">
<div id="loginbox" class="mainbox" style="display: none">
```

Then use javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ((window.location.pathname).indexOf('login') >= 0) {
        $('#loginbox').css("display", "auto");
    } else {
        $('#signupbox').css("display", "auto");
    }
});
```

But I still recommend use different html file to handle signup and login.

Comment: Actually, `show()` = `css("display", "block")` and `hide()` = `css("dispaly", "none"`. But I got an idea from you. Thanks :)